# Json works fine in JAXB, but XML throws exception

Tags: xml, json, list, exception, jaxb

I work on a restful service and use JAXB. Everything works fine in all parts but in my newest part I got an exception when I choose XML for output.

The exception is:

Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.

In all other parts of my service I use List a lot without problems in JSON or XML, but in this case it crashes with XML.

I read a lot about writing extra code for XML or other hints, but it works in other parts of my service without writing any special code for xml.

Maybe there is a really little thing I have to do but at the moment I have absolut no idea whats going on.

Every little hint is welcome

Karsten

Comment: It probably helps us if you paste some examples from your code.